# TextField Listener

Tags: java, swing, scala, jtextfield, keyevent

there's a swing `JTextField`, and I want to add a listener, so whenever the users types a single letter, there's an event. There's a `ValueChanged` event in scala api, but I don't get it what's it's peer. So which one `Listener` should I use? `KeyListener` and implement reasonably just one method?

Comment: You can find an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [Document Listener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) in that case.