# Text Changed event in JTextArea? How to?

Tags: java, swing, events

I have been trying to make a text changed event handling mechanism for my `JTextArea`. For my purposes an event has to be fired whenever there is a change in the text of the `JTextArea`. I tried using the `KeyListener` interface and here is my code for that.

```
txtArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        currentText = text.getText();
        if (currentText == textString)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");

    }
});
```

Nothing happened when the textarea's text matched the hardcoded text. How can an event changed event be made for this.
Can this objective be achieved with a `PropertyChangedListener`? If it can, then how?

Comment: See this question: [**Value Change Listener to JTextField**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I would get the JTextArea's Document via `getDocument()` (a PlainDocument actually) and use a [DocumentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to listen for changes. This way you'd capture changes from key strokes and also from copy/paste/cut events.

Comment: @Prometheus87: thanks for the acceptance. We all answered correctly and at about the same time. So given the above, I wouldn't mind it if you "unaccepted" me and and accepted either of the other two answerers since I don't need the points, if you know what I mean. 1+ to you (and the others).

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels thank you man. Can i contact you on any IM service or Social Network, you seem very resourceful regarding Java.

Comment: No, I'm kind of busy. Best for you to throw your questions here on SO. Luck to you.

Answer (score 46):

Not the JTextArea, but the contained document receives updates, so you need:

```
jTextArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: two things:  'changedUpdate' does not fire for "plain text components" (see Oracle's docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html ) and its argument should be 'e', not 'arg0'.

Comment: and how shouldn't we check the jtextarea.getText() from that listener?

Answer (score 17):

You are comparing strings with ==

```
if (currentText == textString)
```

This will never be true. This compares if the strings are the same String object. You should use equals.

```
if (currentText.equals( textString) )
```

You might also want to check out [DocumentListeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html). 
See also this [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)