# How to add 1000 seperator in real time?

Tags: java, swing, jform-designer

I have created a form using JFormDesigner and need to add a 1000 seperator automatically when the user types a number of 4 digits or more.I have tried the following code but it does not add the seperator(,) real time.

```
int no=Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
String str = String.format("%,d", no);
textField1.setText(str);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @peeskillet i guess he means 1.000 2.040 etc (the dot)

Comment: Please post your expected output too, as 1000 separator in not clear.

Comment: @peeskillet: Depending on the culture, it can be a `,` or a `.`. So one million could be written as `1,000,000` in `en-US` or else as `1.000.000` in `it-IT`.

Comment: use JFormattedTextField with number formatter,

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that it does not add the seperator in real time, then I suspect that you are executing that code upon the click of a button or something similar.

What you would need to do, would be to capture key stroke events and modify the text accordingly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740465/text-changed-event-in-jtextarea-how-to) previous SO post should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DecimalFormat` class to add `,` in number. like

```
 DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###,###");     

 int no=Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
 String str = df.format(no);
 textField1.setText(str);
```

Comment: Thanks Masud.Where should I put the above code to display it real time? I'm new to java ,can't figure it out.                                 I need  to display 1000 as 1,000.

Comment: @user2723764 You should display it on textField1. Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Swing has formatted text fields for this purpose - I think you're looking for [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use this

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
 df.format(no);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get custom grouping separator such as space, do this:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##", symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(bd.longValue()));
```