# Running character countdown in java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jtextarea, charactercount

I can find plenty of Jquery/javascript examples but how is it done in java?

i.e http://jsfiddle.net/timur/47a7A/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 99;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

I've got (64)min/max(256) character input validation on an existing JTextArea but I'd also like a running character countdown to display beneath the textbox like on twitter or what not. No idea how to convert the above to strictly java, if at all ideal.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7740500/3707125?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use KeyListeners:

```
private int max_chrs = 256;

textarea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
         if(textarea.getText().length() >= this.max_chrs){
             e.consume();
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         label.setText( Integer.toString(this.max_chrs - textarea.getText().length()) );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, although I used a DocListener instead so the the backspace key was available.