# Can instantiate the type DocumentListener

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I need to do this: [Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)

I'm trying the solution of Condemwnci, but I'm getting that error in the line:
`textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()`
that in my case is:
`jtxtfBuscarInv.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()`

In my case I want update rows in a Jtable, so my method will be this:
`ordenador.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(jtxtfBuscarInv.getText(), 0));`

I'm on linux, ubuntu 11.10, using Eclipse if that matters.

---

Edit:

I don't understand why, but it works in next way:

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
```

and then overrride the implements methods, instead of doing all in the same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two approaches to adding a `DocumentListener` should be effectively identical. The example below lists *all* the listeners of type `DocumentListener.class` for each event. The obvious one is `DocumentListeners` itself, while the [*anonymous inner class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) has the (implementation dependent) name `DocumentListeners$1`. Both implement the `DocumentListener` interface. The others are part of typical text component maintenance. Note that *two* copies are shown, one from each listener added.

Console:

```
javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$InputMethodRequestsHandler@5090d8ea
DocumentListeners$1@559113f8
DocumentListeners[,0,0,128x38,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler@27b62aab
javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$Handler@28ab54eb

javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$InputMethodRequestsHandler@5090d8ea
DocumentListeners$1@559113f8
DocumentListeners[,0,0,128x38,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler@27b62aab
javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$Handler@28ab54eb
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283067 */
public class DocumentListeners extends JPanel implements DocumentListener {

    JTextField jtf = new JTextField("StackOverflow!");

    public DocumentListeners() {
        this.add(jtf);
        jtf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        jtf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                print(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                print(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                print(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void print(DocumentEvent e) {
        AbstractDocument ad = (AbstractDocument) jtf.getDocument();
        for (DocumentListener dl : ad.getListeners(DocumentListener.class)) {
            System.out.println(dl);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        print(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        print(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        print(e);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("DocumentListeners");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DocumentListeners().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```