# How exactly does actionListener using anonymous objects work?

Tags: java, swing, object, actionlistener, anonymous

I'm kind of confused right now. I have a button let's call it
b1

now I want to add an actionListener so by using anonymous objects I would do this

```
      b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                             ...
                 }
           });
```

I can't understand what an object of ActionListener represents though. Isn't ActionListener an interface? so we're creating an object of an interface? how it this possible and why are we doing this?

when I try this code

```
  ActionListener al = new ActionListener();
```

it gives me an error saying

```
  Cannot instantiate the type ActionListener
```

if I use

```
   ActionListener al;
```

it's correct, but what can I do with al?

thanks in advance

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302423/230513) that contrasts two ways to implement the `DocumentListener` interface.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax:

```
new ActionListener() { ... }
```

defines an anonymous class that implements the `ActionListener` interface. You are not creating an instance of `ActionListener`; you are creating an instance of this anonymous class. (The compiler actually assigns it a name—usually something like `MyEnclosingClass$1`. There will be a separate .class file for this anonymous class.) You can read more about anonymous inner classes in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

You can use this new object immediately in a function call (as with your first code snippet) or you can assign it to a variable that has a type that is assignment-compatible with `ActionListener`.

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) is an interface. Interfaces are meant to be implemented by classes. You ***cannot*** instantiate interfaces.So this would fail:

> ActionListener al = new ActionListener();

In OO parlance, you walk into a fruit shop and ask for a "Fruit". There is nothing like a fruit!. An Orange implements Fruit. An instance of an Orange is available in the basket. Shop keeper can pick that "instance" of orange and give it to you, which is an actual object.

Similarly, you cannot go and ask for a Car. You can only purchase a Car from a particular manufacturer of of a given brand. Here Brand would be an interface.

Now let's see this:

> ActionListener al;

This is equivalent of saying Orange is a Fruit, which is a factual statement.

Suppose you own a BMW Lexus with a registration number AXYZ 67112. Your object is a you car, which extends BMWCars, implements Lexus interface. It is factual making the following claims:

> Car myBMWCar;
> Lexus myBMWCar;

You will need to brush up your OO concepts!

Answer (score 0):

In our programs we face situations in which we need to use any variable or something only once then we don't give it a proper name, because we will be using it only once. Annonymous classes work for the same way.

Same way annonymous classes are the classes without names and we will be used only once in our code, so we don't give them name.

This is a nice example of annonymous classes. Like This object will only be used when Action will be performed on this button.

```
new ActionListener(){
     //code
}
```

This is the syntax of creating annonymous class.

new is for creating object of the class (class without name) and then ActionListener means this class implements this Interface. So now you get simple an object of a class which has no name but provides you ability to override methods of ActionListener interface.