# Best suited JTextComponent

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextcomponent

I've been messing around with various text components and I now come here for answers.

What I need is a area in which user can enter text using keyboard and/or copy/paste.
These are the requirements of the component:

Word wrap, ability to limit number of rows (word wraped ones), ability to prevent user from entering certain characters (or hitting enter for a newline), ability to expand and reduce height according to its content (to make content fit into the component and to have no (couple of pixels are fine) exces height left, ability to detect change of its height, either directly or by tracking the line number.

Comment: Please check out [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) as this will help you phrase your question so it will be easier to answer. Consider creating and posting your [sscce](http://sscce.org) so we can see what you've done so far and get a better handle on what you're trying to do. Please get rid of all reference to "contests" and "winner" as that's not what this site is about.

Comment: Also my recommendation from your similar [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145433/getting-indirect-source-of-documentlistener) about considering use of a JList still stands.

Comment: *"limit number of rows (word wraped ones), .."* It is more common to want to limit the columns/width, especially if it has the *"ability to expand and reduce height"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the different Text Components provided by the Java API here: [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

in the above it has 3 different types of text components:

- Text Controls
- Plain Text Areas
- Styled Text Areas

And it looks like the definition of the last `Styled Text Areas` fits your needs:

> A styled text component can display editable text using more than one
>   font. Some styled text components allow embedded images and even
>   embedded components. Styled text components are powerful and
>   multi-faceted components suitable for high-end needs, and offer more
>   avenues for customization than the other text components. Because they
>   are so powerful and flexible, styled text components typically require
>   more initial programming to set up and use. One exception is that
>   editor panes can be easily loaded with formatted text from a URL,
>   which makes them useful for displaying uneditable help information.

These would include the likes of:

- [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)
- [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) (sub-class of `JEditorPane`)