# Swing: adding a listener to a referenced object doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, listener

So I have a class that contains a JTextField, I reference it using .getField(). When I try to add a listener to it the listener doesn't fire(no error messages. When i add the listener inside the class that defines workspace, everything works. Any ideas?

```
    workspace.getField().getDocument()
            .addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    changed();
                }

                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    changed();
                }

                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    changed();
                }

                public void changed() {
                    System.out.println("changed");
                }
            });
```

.getField():

```
public class ACTTextBox {
    //custom UI for textbox and label
    JTextField input;
    JLabel name;
    public ACTTextBox(int x, int y, int width, int height,String Name){
        input = new JTextField();


name = new JLabel(Name+":");


    }

    public JTextField getField(){return input;}    


public void addTo(JPanel panel){
        panel.add(name);
        panel.add(input);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?  Do you get an error?  Do none of the three functions fire the `changed()` function?

Comment: the change function isn't firing. There's no error message, when i add the listener inside the "workspace" class it works.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `getField()` is actually returning the correct `JTextField`?

Comment: How is the `getField()` function implemented?  Can we see that code?

Comment: Sorry, the code for .getField() is added now.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. The code you posted doesn't help because we don't know the context of how the class is used and how the text field is added to the frame.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302423/230513).