# How to use TextChanged event?

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, documentlistener

I have a text box in which the user enters a unique number. After he enters a number and press tab or enter. I want to write query to search record matching to that unique number. The number is an integer. It will be passport no, pan card no or etc. If it is available in database, I want to display all information of that user.

I don't want to do that on button click.

I was looking for some `TextChanged` event but I found that the alternative in Java is the methods in document listener. But I am not getting how to use that. Also in Netbeans in the design view it does not show me any event on text changed. How to use `Documentlistener` to my `JFrame`/how to fix this?

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield

Comment: If by 'text box' you mean a `JTextField`, add an `ActionListener`.  It will respond to `Enter` at the very least.  Activating on `Tab` is not the path of least surprise (for me at least).

Comment: *"a unique number"*  In what way 'unique'?  Is the number an integer?

Comment: It is an integer. It will be passport no, pan card no or etc. and If it is available into database, i want to display all information of that user.

Comment: From your description of your problem, I don't see how a DocumentListener will help you, since this is for listening to changes in the document as they're being entered, and your problem description does not mention this need. Rather you state that you want to respond to the user pressing "enter" (add an ActionListener to the text component) or to the user leaving the text component via tab (add a FocusListener to the component). The two requirements are not solved by a DocumentListener. I think that before we start chasing wrong solutions, please clarify your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels --> +1; there must be a need for FocusListener (for Tab action) or an `InputMap`, `ActionMap` combo (Enter Key action)..or may be the need is not clear :)

Comment: @Anjali a passport or pan card number cannot be an `Integer` always. Please do recheck the length and size of these _numbers_

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find a [tutorial on `DocumentListeners`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) and example code as well.