# Clicking the textfield and clear the text?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Is it possible that when I clicked the textfield it would clear the recent text that was inputed there?. Mine was like, suppose these are textfields.

```
   Name: Last Name     First Name      Middle Initial
```

Then I would click the Last Name and it would be cleared, same as First Name and Middle Initial. thanks for reading, hope you can help me.

Comment: What is a textchange event? I'd use a FocusListener for this.

Comment: what if the user wants to correct a single character in one of them after navigating to the next one? do you want him/her to start over every time?

Comment: @Hussain: that's why he shouldn't delete the text but instead call `selectAll()` on the JTextComponent. This gives the user the option of doing either.

Comment: @Ravindra: what is a `textchange` event?? Are you thinking Android perchance?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: @Ravindra might want to say `changeUpdate` in `DocumentListener` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)

Comment: @hussain: that would be a mighty strange place to place this type of code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: it doesn't mean that I agree with what @Ravindra has suggested. The idea of resetting the field content on click is something a programmer should avoid as it drives end users crazy, your suggestion of `selectall()` on `focusGained` seems to be the best alternative

Answer (score 6):

Consider a FocusListener, one where all the text is selected:

```
myTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent fEvt) {
    JTextField tField = (JTextField)fEvt.getSource();
    tField.selectAll();
  }
});
```

By selecting all of the text, you give the user the option of either typing and thus deleting the current text and replacing it with the new text, or using the mouse or arrow keys to keep the current text and possibly change it.

Comment: +1 for considering `Help users recognize, diagnose, and recover from errors` ( Ten Usability Heuristics : http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html )

Answer (score 1):

I think Hovercraft is right.  Better to use a `FocusListener` for this purpose.

I would write a utility class that could deal with this, I've done something similar for auto select.  Means I don't have to extend every text component that comes along or mess around with lost of small focus listeners that do the same thing.

```
public class AutoClearOnFocusManager extends FocusAdapter {

    private static final AutoClearOnFocusManager SHARED_INSTANCE = new AutoClearOnFocusManager();

    private AutoClearOnFocusManager() {

    }

    public static AutoClearOnFocusManager getInstance() {
        return SHARED_INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        Component component = e.getComponent();
        if (component instanceof JTextComponent) {
            ((JTextComponent)component).setText(null);
        }
    }

    public static void install(JTextComponent comp) {
        comp.addFocusListener(getInstance());
    }

    public static void uninstall(JTextComponent comp) {
        comp.removeFocusListener(getInstance());
    }        
}
```

Then you just need to use

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField("Some text");
AutoClearOnFocusManager.install(textField);
```

If you're just looking to supply a "prompt" (text inside the field that prompts the user), you could also look at the [Prompt API](http://code.google.com/p/xswingx/)

Comment: your users seem to be masochists ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra you have no idea :P

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the `mouseClicked` event?

So, you can have something like

```
jTextFieldMyText.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jTextFieldMyTextMouseClicked(evt);
    }
});

private void jTextFieldMyTextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    jTextFieldMyText.setText("");
}
```

In the case of focus

```
jTextFieldMyText.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        jTextFieldMyTextFocusGained(evt);
    }
});

private void jTextFieldMyTextFocusGained(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    jTextFieldMyText.setText("");
}
```

If deleting text inmediatelly isn't what's wanted, use `selectAll()` instead of `setText("")` as suggested many times

Comment: And if the user tabs into the field? No a FocusListener would be better, I think.

Comment: Well, depends on user1694994 thoughts... he said that wanted this to happen on clicking, not on focus... anyway, it's an altenative

Comment: With a FocusListener, the behavior will occur on clicking if the current text component does not have focus.

Comment: thanks textchange event worked, but yeah i was wondering about if i tab into the field but not clicking on it how am i supposed to do that?

Comment: I also thought about mouse listener, and even actionListener, but @HovercraftFullOfEels has a very good point about "Tab" to the textfields