# jbutton does not enable even after jtextbox inputmethodtextchanged

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, textchanged

```
private void txtInvCheckinSearchInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                                           

    if(txtInvCheckinSearch.getText().length() <= 0){
        btnInvCheckinOK.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        btnInvCheckinOK.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Did I do this right? What I am aiming for here is for the jbutton to enable itself when the jtextbox is not empty. And if jtextbox is empty, the jbutton disables itself back. (i preset jbutton to .setEnabled(false); in the windowOpened event.

Comment: Read about [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html).

Comment: i did that code in reference to a similar program i did in vb.net... anyways, what i did with it now is....

private void txtInvCheckinSearchKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        if(txtInvCheckinSearch.getText().isEmpty()){
            btnInvCheckinOK.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            btnInvCheckinOK.setEnabled(true);
        }                                               
        
    }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments as it is unreadable. And don't use KeyListeners with text components, instead use a DocumentListener as @MouseEvent correctly suggest. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132452/java-check-if-jtextfield-is-empty-or-not) for more.