# How to perform action on JButton upon Enter on JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField` and a `JButton`, when user hits enter on the `JTextField` then action has to be performed on the corresponding `JButton`. Here is my code snippet.

Also i want to disable the `JButton` on enter and enable it later when something is changed in the `JTextField`

```
JButton jb=new JButton("Print");
JTextField jt=new JTextField(20);
jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
     System.out.println(jt.getText());
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modification of your code, i registered a `DocumentListener` to listen for text changes in `JTextField` and also added `ActionListener` to `JTextField`

```
    jb=new JButton("Print");
    jt=new JTextField(20);

    jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            jb.doClick();
        }
    });

    jt.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
        {
            jb.setEnabled(true);
        }
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
        {
            jb.setEnabled(true);
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
        {
            jb.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            System.out.println(jt.getText());
            jb.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the same action listener to the button and the text field:

```
JButton jb = new JButton("Print");
JTextField jt = new JTextField(20);
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println(jt.getText());
    }
}; 
jb.addActionListener(listener);
jt.addActionListener(listener);
```

Comment: But i didn't write `JButton` and i don't have the `listener` reference! :(

Comment: That's not what your code snippet shows. Had you said that from the start, my answer would have been different.

Answer (score 2):

To perform same action on button click and enter press on Jfield.

```
JButton jb = new JButton("Print");
JTextField jt = new JTextField(20);
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println(jt.getText());
        // Diable Button after action performed.
        jb.setEnabled(false);
    }
}; 
jb.addActionListener(listener);
jt.addActionListener(listener);
```

// Enable Button after any change in JtextField value. JTextField value change Listener refered [from Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)

```
jt.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
        {
            jb.setEnabled(true);
        }
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
        {
            jb.setEnabled(true);
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
        {
            jb.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```