# How to trigger an event on enter key press in JTextField in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a button and a JTextField and if the JTextField is empty a message window opens informing that the field is empty.
Now I want when I enter a number inside the JTextField, the text on the button to change.
But I don't know which code to use.

I used this code

```
               tfInputTinter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        btObserving.setText("Stop Observing");
                    }
                });
```

but nothing happens with the text on the button.
Does anybody have an idea what should I do?
Thanks

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield) help?

Comment: You can always just press ENTER :P

Answer (score 1):

I would say, this will do the trick.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953219/3178834

The person in this post had the same problem I think.

Greetz,
xwavex

Comment: +1, Yes a DocumentListener is the better approach. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You are wanting a KeyListener to listen for events on the keyboard.

```
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Or rather than using the inner type way of working you can implement `KeyListener` in a class and implement the same set of methods in your class.

Comment: -1, A KeyListener was used with AWT. Swing has better API's to use.