# Documentlistener to check wether my textfield is empty or not

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, documentlistener

I have a button that is disabled at default. I want the button enabled when my textfield is no longer empty. I'm trying to use a `documentlistener` but it gives the following error:

```
method addDocumentListener in interface javax.swing.text.Document cannot be applied to given types;
  required: javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
  found: <anonymous DocumentListener>
  reason: actual argument <anonymous DocumentListener> cannot be converted to javax.swing.event.DocumentListener by method invocation conversion
```

Here is my code:

```
    private void tekstveldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    tekstveld.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            changed();
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            changed();
        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            changed();
        }

        public void changed(){
            if (tekstveld.getText().equals("")){
                leegmaken.setEnabled(false);
            }else{
                leegmaken.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    });        
}
```

Comment: have you added an action listener to the same field to which you are adding a document listener too? Show us a little more of your code or write a small test program that explains the issue. I don't quite follow the stack trace you posted above.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  It looks its having a problem converting your `DocumentListener` implementation.  Odd. Maybe try putting the `DocumentListener` in a private class, or a whole other file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you (maybe erroneously) declared your own `class DocumentListener` somewhere else? i.e. what happens if you change

```
tekstveld.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
```

to

```
tekstveld.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new javax.swing.event.DocumentListener(){
```

?

(Although, on an related note, I agree with the comment, above, that setting a document listener *inside* your action performed method seems like a bad idea; this should be set when your form is being created..)

Comment: That crossed my mind too, but this can't be the case as it would be caught during compile time, not runtime.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison the error looks like a compile time message to me :-)

Comment: @WilliamMorrison a runtime message would be a stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

reason: actual argument  cannot be converted to javax.swing.event.DocumentListener by method invocation conversion.