# Value Change Listener to JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I want to know the equivalent event same like change event in VB
i have text box field and i would like to trigger the code once user
made any changes, in text box values ,i need to know how to stick listener to my text box  currently am using  KeyReleased event.

```
 private void jTsearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {  
 String jtr=jTsearch.getText();
 Boolean Txtval=StringUtils.isNumeric(jtr);
  if (Txtval=false) 
   // my code will come here 
  }
  }
```

Comment: You can use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#addCaretListener(javax.swing.event.CaretListener))

Comment: `if (Txtval=false) ` --> Be careful what you're doing here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield

Comment: THANKS Dimitris now ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    jTsearch.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        //whatever you want
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
       //whatever you want
    }
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      //whatever you want
    }
  }
});
```