# Value Change Listener for JavaFX's TextField

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, documentlistener

I would like to add a kind of `listener` to my `JavaFX's TextField` which when ever a user changes the value of the `TextField`, the Application prints something on the console.

I've searched and i find the following very similar question : [Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)

The answer of mentioned question is very clear and efficient, but unfortunately it is only useful for `JTextField` ( Not `JavaFX's TextField`) because it says you should use DocumentListener like this:

```
// Listen for changes in the text
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    warn();
  }
```

but in JavaFX's TextFields you are not able to do it.
So? What is the solution?

(describing with code can be very good but if it is not possible, any hint will be appreciated)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Add a listener to the TextField's textProperty:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("textfield changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
});
```

Comment: This actually make the textfield lose focus, which is quite frustrating for users.

Comment: For those of you using Kotlin, the above snippet looks like this:

`val textField = TextField()`
`textField.textProperty().addListener { observable, oldValue, newValue -> println("textfield changed from $oldValue to $newValue") }`

Comment: Set focus in new Thread(() -> {Platform.runLater(() -> { . It's probably a bug.