# how to make realtime message or character counter in java

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, character, counter

In messages apps, as you type a counter label on the corner gets updated showing the number of characters being entered. How do I create the same thing in Java?

Comment: Use a [listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160899/value-change-listener-for-javafxs-textfield)

Comment: I tried adding listener, it worked but it is passing whatever I type in the textfield to the counter label. What I need is to show the number of characters on realtime just like the one which is under this comment box: it is updating the numbers that show "n characters left".

Comment: Yahoooo! I solved the problem ))

Comment: inputText.textProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
           int c = (int) newValue.length();
           String s = String.valueOf(c);
           inputWordCounter.setText(s);

        }));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve a `IntegerBinding` from the `TextField`'s `text` property containing it's length and convert this to a `StringBinding` in a way that suits your needs. Bind the `text` property of the output `Label` to the result:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    Label label = new Label();
    label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty()
                                       .length()
                                       .asString("Character Count: %d"));
    VBox root = new VBox(label, textField);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```