# How to use setOnKeyTyped in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to detect when the string in a Text Field changes(both when chars are added and when chars are backspaced), to do so I tried using the onKeyTyped function

```
    SearchTF.onKeyTypedProperty(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });
```

This code does not work

So here are my three question

1. Why does this not work
2. How can I get this working
3. Is there a better way to detect when a string in a Text Field changes? (As mentioned in the first line)

Comment: What is `SearchTF`? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value Change Listener for JavaFX's TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160899/value-change-listener-for-javafxs-textfield)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @sonnet it's a text field

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextField.textProperty().addListener((object, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.length() > oldValue.length()) {
                System.out.println("letter add");
            } else {
                System.out.println("letter removed");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! is this the best practice when doing these things?

Comment: While this answer actually addresses the question as directly stated, it would probably end up not behaving the exact way the OP (or the users of his/her application) would want. There are more complex ways that text can change other than simply adding or removing one character at a time. E.g. if the text field contains `"abcd"`, and its all selected, and the user pastes (CTRL-V or mouse) in the string `"acdef"`, this code wouldn't capture the fact that a character (`"b"`) had been removed; there are many other similar scenarios.