# JTextField text not changed

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have the following problem. I create a `JTextField`

```
JTextField t = new JTextField("2");
```

and then add a listener.

```
    t.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getText());

        }
    });
```

But the `getText()` doesn't return the new text.

*For example*, if I type 5, `getText()` still returns 2, the old text.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield) might help

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`keyReleased`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html#keyReleased%28java.awt.event.KeyEvent%29) instead of `keyPressed` method of `KeyAdapter` and  you will get the *updated* value.

Currently, `keyPressed` method will be fired before the text gets updated in your text field. You should get the value when user *release* the key.