# Changing Text dynamically in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing program that uses JTextField's text to draw a string in canvas. The problem is it only does so after the entire text in the JTextField has been entered. How can I change the text in GUI dynamically, meaning each character that is being typed or deleted in JTextField is immediately drawn or deleted in GUI? I've already implemented MVC and have a bunch of actionListeners. Just not sure on what I should use the action listener for this. Scanner? Could somebody please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Please refer to this thread [Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use `DocumentListener` to reach the goal. The details is at [Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)

Changes like "insert", "remove" can be detected at the listener, no need to press `Enter` to trigger them.

Comment: Gearon, worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderNenartovich Glad it helps