# Add and remove JTextField

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtextfield, jcombobox

I want to add and remove `JTextField` controls dynamically using a combo box.

I have a combo box from 1 to 10. For example I press 3 to add 3 text field it works great. But when I press a second time (2) I want to delete the last text field.

This is my code:

```
LineBorder a =new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(Color.black);
String g =(String) nbparam.getSelectedItem();
int x = Integer.parseInt(g);
for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    c=new JTextField();
    c.setText("Paramètre"+(i+1));
    c.setBorder(a);
    c.setSize(200, 28);
    c.setLocation(30,20+43*i);
    jPanel3.add(c);
    jPanel3.revalidate();
    jPanel3.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Before you add anything simply call `jPanel3.removeAll()`. This statements deletes all elements, you're added before.

Comment: thank you very much 
it works

Comment: 1) `c.setSize(200, 28);` That's no better than a guess. Set a number of columns then allow the layout manager to do its job. 2) `c.setLocation(30,20+43*i);` Ugh.. Use a `FlowLayout`. More generally: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: .. 3) `String g =(String) nbparam.getSelectedItem();
int x = Integer.parseInt(g);` Better something like: `int x = nbparam.getSelectedIndex() + 1;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)