# Automatically call controller to save state when user modifies data in realtime

Tags: java, swing

I have a UI like this. Details of the selected item is shown in a separate JPanel.
[image]

User modify the details in the details pane. But I do not want to enforce user to click an update button in the form. Is there a way to update the backend model automatically when user changes something in the details pane?

What I'm thinking to look for losing focus on any of the components in the panel. If the focus is lost, I will check if the data changed in any of the input field. If data changed, controller will be called with the update event. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: If these fields are `JTextField`s [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield) might be the answer. Otherwise please elaborate on what swing components you are currently using and/or add a [mre]

Comment: Generally, that's why there's an update button on most GUIs.  The user lets you know when he's finished making changes.  I suppose you could wait until the JPanel loses focus to determine what to update,

Comment: As you can see it's not just textfield but a bunch of other components. What's the generic solution for this scenario instead of adding document change listener for each component?